# Why does this hold for the mean hitting time?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expectation

Let $X$ be a Markov chain and $T_A$ the hitting time.

My text uses this in a proof:

$$\mathbb E[T_A \ | \ X_0=k ] = \sum_{l\in S} \mathbb P(X_1=l \ | X_0=k\ )(1+\mathbb E[T_A \ | \ X_0=l ])$$

and I don't understand why it holds.

I have tried using $\mathbf 1_C$ yet it wasn't very helpful:

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_C \ | \ X_0=k] & = \mathbb P(C \ | \ X_0=k) 
\\ & =  \sum_{l\in S} \mathbb P(X_1=l \ | X_0=k\ )\mathbb P(C \ | \ X_1=l)
\\ & = ?
\end{align*}

How could I finish the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for every state $\ell$,
$$
E(T_A\,\mathbf 1_{X_1=\ell}\mid X_0=k)=E(T_A\mid X_1=\ell, X_0=k)P(X_1=\ell\mid X_0=k),
$$
and that, if $T_A\geqslant1$ almost surely, that is, if $k\notin A$, then the Markov property at time $1$ yields
$$
E(T_A\mid X_1=\ell, X_0=k)=1+E(T_A\mid X_0=\ell).
$$